# Cannon LBP6020 in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I’ve been trying to install Canon’s LBP6020 printer in Ubuntu 15.10 with no success. I didn't find the printer's driver in system setting,

I googled it, and all the solutions I’ve found deal with Ubuntu 12 / 13 or 14.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

[Canon-europe](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6020.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20%2864-bit%29) has a linux driver for this printer, which includes deb files for 32 and 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying a generic Canon driver, run a test page, then try a generic PS (PostScript) driver.